# How to import files when shadowing a file, without adding them to the local directory?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am new to *Gatsby* and *React*. I have set up a site using LekoArts' gastby-theme cara

I understand that what I create in the theme folder (src/@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-cara) will shadow the files seen in the theme's src folder. Which can be viewed here on github:

https://github.com/LekoArts/gatsby-themes/tree/master/themes/gatsby-theme-cara/src

What I **want** to do is shadow the "templates/cara.tsx" file, there I am able to affect the size of different sections in the theme.

The issue is that that .tsx file has many other components that need to be imported that I don't want to shadow, how do I import these files that are on the themes directory (without having to shadow them as well)?

[Here's a screenshot of the "templates/cara.tsx" file and all it's imports underlined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0mu9.png)

*I have tried shadowing all files that need to be imported, but it got out of hand as they all have their own dependencies that need to be imported as well.*

Thanks for your time

Comment: You want to import your own components, isn't?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future that gets confused by this same thing:

You can access the theme's files using:

import Layout from "@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-cara/src/components/layout"

If you are using a different gatsby-theme check 'gatsby-config.js' look for plugins: [ { resolve: **`use this path for accessing it's src`**,

for my theme it gives **"@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-cara"** so I then add src/components/layout to access the layout component (without having to shadow it locally).